# Difference between Name Attribute and Name Token? (HTML)

Tags: html, token

I was checking into whether I could use spaces safely in a name attribute and the overwhelming consensus (apart from one answer which the community said was incorrect) was that it is just fine, because the Name attribute uses CDATA token instead of a Name token, or something along those lines.  The problem is I can't seem to find information on what the heck that actually means.

What is a name token?  If the name attribute doesn't use one, what is the point?  What exactly is a token, for that matter?  I'm finding some information on the subject, but it all seems to be over my head.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokens can be roughly defined as a sequence of characters that represent something and follow a specific pattern. You might find this [overview](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/courses/COP402001/notes3_4.pdf) on Programming Language Syntax as a good start for basic definitions. The various types of supported tokens can be found at [the w3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata) and is listed as the following:

> CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and
>   may include character entities. User agents should interpret attribute
>   values as follows: Replace character entities with characters, Ignore
>   line feeds, Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.
>   User agents may ignore leading and trailing white space in CDATA
>   attribute values (e.g., "   myval   " may be interpreted as "myval").
>   Authors should not declare attribute values with leading or trailing
>   white space.
>
> For some HTML 4 attributes with CDATA attribute values, the
>   specification imposes further constraints on the set of legal values
>   for the attribute that may not be expressed by the DTD.
>
> Although the STYLE and SCRIPT elements use CDATA for their data model,
>   for these elements, CDATA must be handled differently by user agents.
>   Markup and entities must be treated as raw text and passed to the
>   application as is. The first occurrence of the character sequence "
>
> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). IDREF and IDREFS
>   are references to ID tokens defined by other attributes. IDREF is a
>   single token and IDREFS is a space-separated list of tokens. NUMBER
>   tokens must contain at least one digit ([0-9]).

Just because the token is called NAME doesn't necessarily mean it was meant for the name attribute. It's just an coincidence of like terms and the name attribute is a separate concept from the NAME SGML token. If you look at the table of [Index of Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html)) you can see the types of tokens each attribute is expected to use.

Comment: The distinction is somewhat easier to make if `NAME` as an SGML token (which is what it really is here) is written consistently in all uppercase, as the SGML standard does, and the HTML attribute name is written in all lowercase, `name`, which is the common spelling.

Comment: I've updated my references to the SGML token to use the all upper case spelling.

Comment: It should be noted that browsers don't actually do all that stuff about ignoring line feeds and replacing carriage returns and tabs. See http://jsfiddle.net/UuFjg/1/

Answer (score 0):

The lexical analyzer reads the stream of characters making up the source program and groups the characters into meaningful sequences called lexemes. For each lexeme, the lexical analyzer produces as output a token of the form

```
  <token-name, attribute-value>
```

that it passes on to the subsequent phase, syntax analysis.

In the token, the first component **token-name** is an abstract symbol that is used during syntax analysis, and the second component **attribute-value** points to an entry in the symbol table for this token. Information from the symbol-table entry is needed for semantic analysis and code generation.

Comment: This is in the context of compiler construction.